# I want to use an object in my ActionListener Class

Tags: java, static, actionlistener

I m trying to implement my code of a card game that worked into a gui. I have problems in using my Deck in an ActionListener class. Deck is an object of the Class Deck and has as variables/instances(I dont know the correct terminology) an ArrayList and some methods to pick one card from the Deck etc. The code for the actionlistener class is this:

```
class Play  implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {          
        Card a1, a2, b1, b2;


        a1 = Deck.pickCard(Deck.Deck);

        String Player2="Player2";
        String Player1="Player1";
        int score1=0;
        int score2=0;
        System.out.println(Player1 + " drew a " + a1.getName(a1) + " of " + a1.getType(a1));
        a2 = Deck.pickCard(Deck.Deck);
        System.out.println(Player1 + " drew a " + a2.getName(a2) + " of " + a2.getType(a2));
        b1 = Deck.pickCard(Deck.Deck);

        System.out.println(Player2 + " drew a " + b1.getName(b1) + " of " + b1.getType(b1));
        b2 =Deck.pickCard(Deck.Deck);
        System.out.println(Player2 + " drew a " + b2.getName(b2) + " of " + b2.getType(b2));
        if (a1.getValue(a1) + a2.getValue(a2) > b1.getValue(b1) + b2.getValue(b2)) {
            score1 = score1 + 1;
            System.out.println(Player1 + " win and has " + score1 + " points");
        }
        if (a1.getValue(a1) + a2.getValue(a2) < b1.getValue(b1) + b2.getValue(b2)) {
            score2 = score2 + 1;
            System.out.println(Player2 + " win and has " + score2 + " points");
        }
    } 
}
```

If I set a constructor of the `Deck` class inside the class `Play` the code runs normally, but every time the Deck recreates and the cards picked are not removed from the Deck. As I was typing this question I remembered that the scores are getting refreshed as well.I tried putting this piece of code into a method and try to call the method inside the class Play but that does not seem to work  either, my text is underlined with red saying that `a non static method cannot be referenced from a static context`. I'm new to programming in general and these problems with inheritance and variables seem too awkward and weird for now. What I would like to ask if possible is how to approach this kind of problem since I've put up a big amount of work for the previous part of the exercises.Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried to fix your code formatting, in particular the code indentations, since poorly formatted code is difficult to read and understand code. In the future, you're going to want to do this yourself, to give your code proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Your cooperation in this would be greatly appreciated and will likely improve your chances of getting a decent and prompt answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're exact situation is, but maybe you need to make your constructor for Play accept a Deck as an argument:

```
class Play implements ActionListener {
    Deck deck;
    public Play(Deck deck) {
        this.deck = deck;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can do `addActionListener(new Play(deck));` and give Play a reference to your Deck.

Comment: Yeap that was my problem since I couldnt use my  object. I didnt know how to set up the constructor because it was a class that had a weird format